# How do I generate a source of netflow data for nfcapd?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, tshark, netflow

I am trying to use nfcapd to save netflow files for use by a network analysis tool.

How do I capture network traffic on my host and send it into nfcapd? Can I use wireshark/tshark or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You need a sensor software, if your host that would send netflow data is Linux, you could try `ipt-netflow` or `softflowd` for this purpose.

Comment: If you google the term "netflow exporter" or "software netflow exporter" you'll come up with a couple more. ("exporter" seems to be the more common term than "sensor" for some reason)